# jQuery - Animate css background-size?

Tags: jquery, animation, css

I'm trying to animate the size of my background image, but it's not working - Any idea why from the following code?

```
$(this).animate({'opacity' : 1, 'background-size':'70px 48px', 'right':39, 'top':45}, 250);
```

Note: all the other properties animate correctly, it's just the background-size that doesn't update.

Thanks!

Comment: you can apply custom animation separatelly that will do this for you. $(this).animate({'opacity' : 1, 'right':39, 'top':45}, {duration : 250, step: function(stepsLeft){});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `background-size` is a CSS3 property that is not supported by jQuery yet as it's still a [candidate for recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/).

See this [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundSize).

Comment: any change on this? that plugin page is no longer found

Comment: @Tom: Thanks for not providing any links! It's way easier now, since this thread is first (and only) one in Google results actually related to question ;) [I used different queries].

Comment: Here is the plugin suggested:

http://louisremi.github.com/jquery.backgroundSize.js/demo/

Answer (score 0):

Old link chain forwards to [this plugin](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill)
But it's quite hard to find function that answers this question.