# How to animate background-size of multiple background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I simply can not animate the `background-size` property.

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="intern-bar">
        R$ <span id="funds">000,00</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS (with jQuery):

```
$(".intern-bar").animate({backgroundSize: "100% 100%, 100%"}, function(){
    console.log("done")
});
```

CSS (SCSS):

```
body {
  background-color: black;
     }
.bar {
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 7px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    .intern-bar {
        padding: 6px 15px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 100px;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #00C1EB, #00c1eb) 
        no-repeat, linear-gradient(to right, rgba(182, 182, 182, 
        0.54), rgba(121, 121, 121, 0.40)) no-repeat;
        background-size: 56% 100%, 100%;
        background-position: 0%, 10%;
        height: 100%;
        min-width: 155px;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 200;
        line-height: 1;
        transition: 0.8s ease;
        #funds {
            font-weight: 500;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've stumble upon this answer:

> Because background-size is a CSS3 property that is not supported by jQuery yet as it's still a candidate for recommendation.

From this question: [jQuery - Animate css background-size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269786/jquery-animate-css-background-size)
And none of the answers that I've come across worked for me, and I *need* to use the callback function of animate, to do something when it's finished, like a confetti animation, etc

Pen: https://codepen.io/Malganis/pen/MvXLxY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions:

- (jQuery) *Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected 
  elements.*

  ```
  $(element).on();
  ```
- (Standard JS) The transitionend event occurs when a CSS transition has completed

  ```
  element.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
    console.log("Done");
  }, false);
  ```

  [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1n7n8uL/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/uqm8o4f2/), I used `CSS animations`.

I just modified your `CSS` and the `JQUERY` :) hope this can help you.

Comment: Ty, but there's no callback for when the animation is complete in `.addClass()` method, therefore I can't opt for this solution.

Comment: I have added alert

Comment: and setTimeout function that corresponds with the animation time